# GWT RPC - Parallel asynchronous calls

Tags: ajax, gwt, rpc, gwt-rpc, gquery

I have a list of promises that needs to be executed in parallel and in an asynchronous manner.Say,i have,

```
List<Promise<X>> list;
```

Once all the parallel request completes, i need to make another request say "Y". Here is my GWT code,

```
GQuery.when(list).done(...).fail(..)
```

But the above doesn seem to work!.How can i pass a list of promises to GQuery?.Is the above synctax valid?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a sample GWT project in Eclipse, a simple asynchronous RPC call is created. You can take that as a template to change it the way you need. With the callback of the request is it possible to display your "Y".

```
// Set up the callback object.
AsyncCallback<List<Promise<X>>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<Promise<X>>>() {
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO: Do something with errors.
    }

    public void onSuccess(List<Promise<X>> result) {
        // TODO: DO something with the result.
    }
};
```

You should also read the documentations, at least...
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html